# how to get String data from jsonobject

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a json array like below and want to get firstname and lastname from form it any help form guzs please

```
{
    "message": "Verification",
    "data": {
        "accountStatus": "OPEN",
        "firstName": "Y",
        "lastName": "SHITTU",
        "customerType": "SUD",
        "invoicePeriod": 1,
        "dueDate": "2017-09-09T00:00:00+01:00",
        "customerNumber": 309804811
    },
    "status": "success"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//First create JSON object from the json...    
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
//Then get firstname and lastname as string...
String firstName = obj.getJSONObject("data").getString("firstName");
String lastName = obj.getJSONObject("data").getString("lastName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you reading Json Parsing first. Just Googled and got this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm).

Parser for your response in the question:
(response is the Json you have as String type)

```
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject(response);

    JsonObject data = json.getJsonObject("data");

    String firstName = data.getString("firstName");
    String lastName = data.getString("lastName");
```

Comment: should i  send a String request or Jsonobject Request

Comment: I assume you are using volley from the tag of the question. you can use either one. If you are using String request, you have to create JsonObject like the first line in my answer. If you are using JsonRequest, you can skip the first line.

Comment: You can also try data.optString("firstName"); . optString helps to get rid out of null pointer exception when you don't get data from jsonObject.

Comment: Here's how I would choose between getString and optString. If I am sure that the response would contain the specified key, then I will use getString. In that case, if by some bug in the server, I get a response without that key, the app should crash (Fail Fast pattern) and so we can correct the response at the server. On the other hand, if am sure that there are some keys which might not present in the response depends on some factors, I will use optString with some default value as fallback.